# Impact of custom domain on existing integration

Tags: integration, single-sign-on, custom-domain

We're planning to create a custom domain as this is a prerequisite for SSO (desktop & salesforce1). The [help article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=domain_name_guidelines.htm&language=en_US) states that the API integration with salesforce where the pod/instances (CS80, EU2 etc) are referred should continue to work without any issues. But usually these article miss out out mentioning limitations.

I would like to know if there are any gotcha / limitation that you have faced which which impacted the existing integrations (to and from salesforce) with the introduction of custom domain?

Answer (score 1):

One possible situation:

1. Two SFDC orgs with an existing REST callout from org A to org B
2. Org B switched to a custom domain
3. Integration broke because `Security Controls | Remote Site Settings | Remote Site URL` referenced a URL like `https://na5.salesforce.com`

**Solution**

Update SFDC org's Remote Site Settings to `https:orgBCustomDomain.my.salesforce.com`

Comment: That's not really an issue (for now), as long as the domain is allowed to redirect. Haven't tried it with redirect disabled, though.

Comment: Hmm. Above was based on personal experience. I had control over OrgA but not OrgB who made the switch to custom domain without prior notification

Comment: @crop1645 thanks for your thoughts. Luckily we do not have connected orgs, so that off the list. One another thing that was odd was that when I generated the WSDL for one of the webservice, the endpoint still pointed to the old instance URL and not the domain url. WOuld you know why that would happen?

Comment: @sfdcfox One another thing that was odd was that when I generated the WSDL for one of the webservice class, the endpoint still pointed to the old instance URL and not the domain url. WOuld you know why that would happen?